# Как сделать стороны в блоки div под наклоном?

Tags: css3, html5

Есть блок

```
<body>

<div>
</div>

</body>
```

Хочу, чтоб у этого блока были стороны под наклоном. Допустим, верхняя сторона должна быть больше, чем нижняя, а границы по сторонам сужались.

Можно ли так сделать с помощью css?

Comment: [Геометрические фигуры на CSS](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/)

Answer (score 2):

https://webformyself.com/transformaciya-i-maski-css-naklonnye-kraya/
http://htmlbook.ru/blog/maskirovanie-v-css

Вот мне тоже нужен был блок, у которого верх и низ под уклоном, вот эта ссылка помогла, а конкретно вот такая запись, может и тут пригодится))

```
div{
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0 100%);
}
```